# как писать сообщение в чат Minecraft в свёрнутом режиме, Python

Tags: python, minecraft

как писать сообщение в чат Minecraft в свёрнутом режиме, Python

нужно чтобы на сервере, от имени игрока писалась в чат определённая строка.

раньше писал через keyboard
но это дико неудобно, т.к. чат открывается и из-за того что персонаж в движении, пишется некорректно, к примеру wwwПривет мир!

Comment: У вас есть хотя бы попытки самому написать данный код? Если да, то приложите в вопросе

Comment: Разве в библиотеке keyboard нет возможности временно заблокировать сигналы внешней клавиатуры? Попробуйте найти такую возможность и просто используйте ее перед выполнением вашего написанного скрипта

Comment: скорее вам нужно чтото для работы с сетевыми пакетами. можно выловить отправление 'привет' и повторить. даже без расшифровки. и там будет пофигу окно свёрнуто или нет.

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто перед печатью текста зажимать клавишу ctrl а после печати отпускать. При зажатой клавише ctrl текст с клавиатуры не печатается. А с питона продолжает.